# Creating custom menu with custom themes

Tags: menus, themes

I have created my own custom WordPress theme and am now trying to implement the custom menu.

I noticed with the default theme that when I went to *Appearance > Menus*, I was able to create my menu based on the pages I had, but after installing my own custom theme, I could not locate *Appearance > Menus*. And by that I mean there was no *Menus* option under *Appearance* in WordPress.

So now I do not know how to go about it, because this is my first WordPress site.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org):

> **Navigation Menu** is a [theme feature](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Features) introduced with [Version 3.0](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.0). WordPress includes an easy to use mechanism for introducing customised navigation menus into a theme. In order to incorporate menu support into your theme, *you need to add a few code segments to your theme files*.

You should [familiarize yourself with how to add those to a theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus).
You will primarily need [`register_nav_menus`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus) and [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).